I got hit with a spell carrying "Personal fireball thrower". How long will I throw fireballs everywhere?
I have a good run going, and one of those wizards that make your own spells hurt you hit me, then I hit myself with a wand that had "Personal fireball thrower" on it.  I am now throwing fireballs constantly, like 4-5 per second.  It's making it impossible to play.  It sets me on fire, the explosions knock me around, and the noise is loud and grating.
There is no status timer anywhere telling me how long this'll last.  Is this ever going to end?  Or should I just start a new run?


The effect will end when around 83 seconds have passed, or when the affected entity dies, whichever comes first. This timer is reset
if the entity polymorphs.

https://noita.wiki.gg/wiki/Personal_Fireball_Thrower

If you are struck with this effect and do not have the explosion
immunity perk, it's pretty much game over unless you have large
amounts of health or consistent healing.

https://noita.fandom.com/wiki/Personal_Fireball_Thrower
